# Uk-modal set bgclose via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [uk-modal](http://getuikit.com/docs/modal.html) on a project.

As you can see from the documentation, to open a modal via a link this is what you do:

```
<a href="#!" data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal_loading', bgclose:false}" id="open_loading_modal">Modal</a>
```

I ***really need*** to have the `bgclose:false` set (so that the modal does not disappear on clicking on the background).

The point I need to reach is to open the modal via Javascript (and not on a link as above).

This is the normal script I would use (shortened):

```
UIkit.modal("#modal_loading").show();
```

On the documentation I cannot find the way of setting the `bgclose` to `false` **via Javascript**.

The workaround I made for now is to make an invisible (`display:none`) link as above and trigger its click event:

```
$('#open_loading_modal').trigger('click');
```

But this is ..... boring.

How do I set `bgclose` to `false` via Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

```
UIkit.modal("#modal_loading", {bgclose: false}).show();
```